# Append all values of array to one table row

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an AJAX request which returns an array from my database like this:

```
$objet['name']
$objet['date']
$objet['amount']
```

When I do an `each` function it does an iteration for each rows and keys,

I would like to make one iteration for each rows and to display data in table row. Below is my code :

```
$("#show_debours").dialog("open");
    var groupe_debours = $(this).closest('tr').find('.groupe').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "requetes_ajax/fetch_debours_detail.json.php",
        data: "groupe=" + groupe_debours,
        success: function(data){
            $('.remove').remove();
            $.each(data, function (data) {
                $('#fetchdebours tr:last').after('<tr class="remove"><td>' + data.libelle_debours + '</td><td>' + data.date + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ht_tva + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ht_no_tva + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ttc  + '</td></tr>')
                //alert(key + ': ' + value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

All works fine, but instead of returning one row with all value, it returns as many rows as there is rows and variables

For example if I have 3 rows in my database it returns to me 9 lines in my table. It should not.

In php I do

```
<?php
    foreach($data as $row):
        echo "<tr><td>{$data['name']}</td><td>{$data['date']}</td>{$data['amount']}</tr>";
    endforeach;
?>
```

This works fine it returns to me 3 row with all values filled. I would like the same in jQuery but I do not know how. I've done some research with no success.

Any kind of help will be much appreciated

Comment: So this doesn't really have anything to do with sql, or mysql - and not much to do with php?

Comment: _"jquery array"_ - What's that? Snark aside, it would help if you showed exactly what is in the Ajax response.

Comment: the ajax callback is the one <?php

session_start();
require_once('../../config/config.inc.php');
include '../lib_php/getcash.php';
// on vérifie toujours qu'il s'agit d'un membre qui est connecté
if (!isset($_SESSION['id'])) {
    // si ce n'est pas le cas, on le redirige vers l'accueil
    header('Location: ../');
    exit();
}
header('Content-type: application/json');
$groupe = $_POST['groupe'];
$result = fetchDebouursByGroupe($groupe);
echo json_encode($result);

Answer (score 1):

It creates multiple rows because you are creating a `tr` element in each iteration. Try this:

```
success: function(data){
    $('.remove').remove();
    var $tr = $('<tr />', { 'class': 'remove' });
    $.each(data, function (data) {
        $tr.append('<td>' + data.libelle_debours + '</td><td>' + data.date + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ht_tva + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ht_no_tva + '</td><td>' + data.debours_montant_ttc + '</td>');
    });
    $('#fetchdebours tr:last').after($tr);
}
```

Comment: Two rows? Your whole question states you want all values on one row...?

Comment: no in fact I mean value is 
something like that

$objet['name']
$objet['date']
$objet['amount']

but I want  horizontal show them, but the array has got many records so this record should be vertically displayed

Comment: actualy I have has many rows as there is rows in the array multipe by the number of columns

Comment: in the database for one query I have two records, who have got 4 columns (data, amount, name and id). 

Using the foreach I would like to display that line in my table.

Actually I have 2 row * 3 fields that display to me 6 line. I would like just 2 rows as in database